# plot the GPS coordinates on ox.plot_graph

Tags: osmnx

I have a GPS point, say (39.6654413, 20.8586396), then i can get the graph with method in OSMNx: ox.graph_from_point. I note that ox.plot_graph can plot this graph. My problem is can i plot the GPS point on this graph ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Per the [documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.plot.plot_graph), the `plot_graph` function returns a matplotlib figure and axis as a tuple. You can use that axis object to plot a point as per normal [with matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html).

Answer (score 0):

Let ogp is your ox.graph_from_point
then you may try something like this:

```
lat,lon =  (39.6654413, 20.8586396)
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(ogp, show=False, close=False,node_alpha=.2,edge_alpha=.3, 
bgcolor='w',node_color='b', node_size=1)
plt.plot(lon,lat,c='b',marker='o')
plt.show()
```